# #Error on Local Reporting

Tags: reporting, rdlc, localreport

I'm having trouble with an RDLC using Local Reporting. I pass a 'QOI' object into the report, and I'm trying to get it to read the customer information.

The QOI object contains a customer object. This customer object has fields such as first name, last name, mid name, addresses, etc. I need to check if the QOI objects customer is null, and if not, write the firstName to a text box. So I've been trying this code...

```
=IIF(
    IsNothing(First(Fields!customer.Value, "QOI")),
    "Cash Sale", 
    First(Fields!customer.Value.firstName(), "QOI")
)
```

But that will just make the textbox say '#Error', with or without a customer attached. So, I tried this way.

```
=First(
    IIF(
        IsNothing(Fields!customer.Value),
        "Cash Sale", 
        Fields!customer.Value.firstName()
    )
    , "QOI"
)
```

but this one gives me an #Error if theres no customer, or it says 'The specified operation is not valid' if there IS a customer... However, the following code works perfectly for stores.

```
=First(
    IIF(
        IsNothing(Fields!store.Value),
        "Store Not Set", 
        Fields!store.Value.name()
    )
    , "QOI"
)
```

I've checked my variable names, intercepted the object and made sure everything was accurate... it just seems to hate customers. What could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution I could find was to create a custom object specifically for this report, and use a method that takes a QOI object and spits out a QOIReceipt object that has everything already populated. If anyone can see where I'm going wrong please let me know, otherwise the custom object seems to be the way to go.

Comment: IIf evaluates all arguments so if any argument generates an error, then the entire function will throw an error. i.e.: in the second expression if IsNothing(Fields!customer.Value) then you can't access his .firstName.